# Bat file stopping and i'm not sure why

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

So, I have a bat file I've been building to do a simple profile backup/restore.  I'm running Windows 7 64bit.

I get through 99% of the script until it gets to this point and then dies.  To be clear, in the environment I'm working in, I HAVE to turn off UAC for certain things.  Someone much higher up than me made that call.

However, this needs to do this but it dies after the "[ COMPLETE ]" is echoed.  It doesn't close the window, it just goes back to the C prompt.

The only other thing it's going (trying) to do after that is log the user off after a 15 second timer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
echo [ Turning off UAC... ]
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul
echo [ COMPLETE ]
ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul
echo.
ECHO ==========================================================
ECHO =                   Restore Complete                     =
ECHO =   Computer will logoff in 15 seconds to apply changes. =
ECHO ==========================================================
TIMEOUT 16
shutdown /l
@pause
:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a test batch file that does what you're trying:

```
@echo off
echo before
cmd /k echo I'm doing it!
echo after
```

And here was the result:

```
C:\files\j>test
before
I'm doing it!
```

So I changed it to call:

```
@echo off
echo before
call echo I'm doing it!
echo after
```

And got this:

```
C:\files\j>test
before
I'm doing it!
after
```

So clearly, `/k` isn't for you. But CALL will put it in a new shell... So my recommendation is to just change that line to be :

```
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

No cmd, no \k, no anything - just run the REG.exe.

If you have to, use the CALL since you're adding a registry key and it should stay there.

Comment: Ahh, you're right.  I went far too complicated with it.  Regular old reg add and it worked a charm.

Thanks!

Comment: If you had needed to use `cmd` for some reason the correct switch is `/c` rather than `/k`.  The `/k` option runs the command and then prompts the user for additional commands.  (If you had typed "exit" the rest of the batch file would have run.)

Comment: `/c` wouldn't have killed his current session? Or are you saying that because the cmd spawns a new shell, the `/c` would have killed THAT shell, returning him to the shell he wanted to continue with?